# Way to keep track of rounds during a while loop

Tags: python, random, infinite

So I'm trying to keep track of what is played in a round by each player and who wins each round in my R/P/S program. Is there a way to do that in a, possibly, infinitely repeating loop? Here's the code

```
import random
Round = 0
Player_Score = 0
Computer_Score = 0
while Player_Score < 5 and Computer_Score < 5:
    Player_object = input("Would you like to choose R, P, or S?")
    Computer_object = random.sample("RPS", 1)[0]
    if Player_object == "R" or Player_object == "r":
        if Computer_object == "R":
             print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
        elif Computer_object == "P":
            Computer_Score += 1 
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ". You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")
        else:
            Player_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")


    if Player_object == "P" or Player_object == "p":
        if str(Computer_object) == "R":
            Player_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")
        elif str(Computer_object) == "P":
           print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ". You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
        else:
            Computer_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")


    if Player_object == "S" or Player_object == "s":
        if str(Computer_object) == "R":
             print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")
        elif str(Computer_object) == "P":
            Computer_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ". You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")
        else:
            Player_Score += 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
if Computer_Score == 5 and Player_Score != 5:
    print("The Computer has won!")
if Player_Score == 5 and Computer_Score != 5:
    print("You have won and beaten the computer")
R = "Rock"
r = "Rock"
P = "Paper"
p = "Paper"
S = "Scissors"
s = "Scissors"
```

Comment: Just create a list before your `while` loop starts and append the results to that list for each outcome. You should also consider learning about functions as your code is very repetitive - Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to handle something like this is to use a list where you would store the information you want in each round.

Before your loop, create an empty list

```
Rounds = []
```

and at the end of your loop, append the relevant information.
You can use a tuple to add multiple pieces of information as a single entry in the list. For example, to add what is played by each player, you could write

```
Rounds.append((Player_object, Computer_object))
```

If you want to keep track of who won the round, add this information in a variable in your `if`/`else` and add it to the tuple.

Once your loop is over, you can access the information of each round by accessing this list. List indexes start at `0`, so to access the information of the first round, you would write `Rounds[0]`. Each element in a tuple can also be accessed by index, so the `Player_object` of round 1 can be accessed using `Rounds[0][0]`.

If you need more information, try to search for lists and tuples in Python.

Answer (score 0):

For each round, you want to store two things, right? The players and their moves, and their winner. In a round, a player moves only once, so we would want a tuple of (player, move) in our data structure. There could be many players participating in one round, so using a `list` would be most suitable. Therefore in each round, you can have a list of tuples of (player, move).

Since with each round, you want to keep track of the winner also, you can make a tuple to represent a round: ([list of players and moves], winner).

Finally, you want a list of these! Define this list outside the game loop, but append the data of a round at the end of each loop to this list. H

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -2):

infinity loop......here you go

```
import random

Round = {}
while True:
    cnt = 1
    ans = raw_input("Wanna Play RPS (y/n) ? ")
    if ans == 'y' or ans == 'Y':
        Player_Score = 0
        Computer_Score = 0
        while Player_Score < 5 and Computer_Score < 5:
            Player_object = raw_input("Would you like to choose R, P, or S? ")
            Computer_object = random.sample("RPS", 1)[0]
            if Player_object == "R" or Player_object == "r":
                if Computer_object == "R":
                    print("You have chosen " + Player_object + " and the Computer chose " + str(
                    Computer_object) + ".You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
                elif Computer_object == "P":
                    Computer_Score += 1
                    print("You have chosen " + Player_object + " and the Computer chose " + str(
                    Computer_object) + ". You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")
                else:
                    Player_Score += 1
                    print("You have chosen " + Player_object + " and the Computer chose " + str(
                    Computer_object) + ".You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")

            if Player_object == "P" or Player_object == "p":
                if str(Computer_object) == "R":
                    Player_Score += 1
                    print("You have chosen " + Player_object + " and the Computer chose " + str(
                    Computer_object) + ".You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")
                elif str(Computer_object) == "P":
                    print("You have chosen " + Player_object + " and the Computer chose " + str(
                    Computer_object) + ". You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
                else:
                    Computer_Score += 1
                    print("You have chosen " + Player_object + " and the Computer chose " + str(
                    Computer_object) + ".You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")

            if Player_object == "S" or Player_object == "s":
                if str(Computer_object) == "R":
                    print("You have chosen " + Player_object + " and the Computer chose " + str(
                    Computer_object) + ".You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")
                elif str(Computer_object) == "P":
                    Computer_Score += 1
                    print("You have chosen " + Player_object + " and the Computer chose " + str(
                    Computer_object) + ". You have beaten the Computer and you have scored a point.")
                else:
                    Player_Score += 1
                    print("You have chosen " + Player_object + " and the Computer chose " + str(
                    Computer_object) + ".You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")

            if Computer_Score == 5 and Player_Score != 5:
                Round[cnt] = "Computer"
                print("The Computer has won!")
            elif Player_Score == 5 and Computer_Score != 5:
                Round[cnt] = "Player"
                print("You have won and beaten the computer")
    else:
        break

cnt += 1
R = "Rock"
r = "Rock"
P = "Paper"
p = "Paper"
S = "Scissors"
s = "Scissors"

for i in Round:
    print "Round ", i, "won by ", Round[i], "\n"
```

Comment: And how does this "keep track of what is played in a round by each player and who wins each round"?